# Autocomplete not working correctly in VS2010 for data members, but works for methods

Tags: visual-studio-2010, autocomplete

I just noticed this recently, but I don't know if it ever worked.

if I have a class like

```
class Foo
{
public:
    DoStuff();

    bool flag;
};
```

and I type in

```
Foo f;
f.D
```

followed by ctrl+space, I get the intellisense list which includes `DoStuff` and I can just press enter (maybe first selecting it with arrow keys) and it will get pasted into the editor.

but if I do

```
Foo f;
f.f
```

followed by ctrl+space, `flag` appears on the list, but if I try to select it with enter, it just cancels the list, putting nothing into the editor.

Is this a visual studio bug, or a setting I have to enable somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Try hit Ctrl+Alt+Space to re-enable autocompletion
If it's not working do the following

1. devenv.exe /ResetSettings
2. devenv /resetuserdata
3. Goto Toos -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages to see if all options under Statement completion are checked